# How do try...catch statements really work in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a `foreach()` loop in this function and by searching the internet I know, that for each loop doesn't work in IE.
To save my time I simply put a: `try {} catch {}` around it, but IE still reminds me, by function call, that there is an error.

Why does IE 11 work ? **Code:**

Code:

```
function classAndIdSpy() {

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spy");
var page_you_on = window.location.href.split("/");
var json56 = '{ "div_ids_classes" : [{"PAGE":"'+page_you_on[page_you_on.length-1]+'"},';

try {
   // Block of code to try. 
for(var xy of x) { 

json56 += '{"SPY_ID":"'+xy.id+'","CLASS":"'+xy.parentNode.className+'","ID":"'+xy.parentNode.id +'"}';

json56 += (x.length-1 > [].indexOf.call(x, xy)) ? ',' : '';

}
json56 += ']}';

req.open('POST', '../admin/id_class_colect.php', true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.send("json2="+json56);

var status;
req.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        status = req.responseText;        
        console.log("Send ajax. Colected Id and Class information of content DIVs into database. Status:"+status);         
    }}
}
catch(err) {
      console.log("Your browser doesn't support ID and Class information of content DIV into database. Please use another browser.");
       return false;   
   } 
} //End of ClassAndIDspy
```

**I get the following error in the console: SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' (The function works fine in Firefox, and I don't think there is a semicolon missing)**

And, this is the part I would like Internet Exporer to ignore:
**Code:**

```
for(var xy of x) { 

json56 += '{"SPY_ID":"'+xy.id+'","CLASS":"'+xy.parentNode.className+'","ID":"'+xy.parentNode.id +'"}';

json56 += (x.length-1 > [].indexOf.call(x, xy)) ? ',' : '';

}
```

Thank you for any help !

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Frankly, why do you bother with a `for (xy of x)` loop here?  You're using the index of the element, in `[].indexOf.call`, so I don't see why you don't just use a plain old `for` loop here.

Comment: if you want to get a job somewhere and keep it, learn to use proper indentation, this code is unreadable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to have misunderstood the point of `try`-`catch`.

`try` and `catch` are used to handle exceptions that arise when your JavaScript code runs.  Your code doesn't get to run in IE because it fails to compile.  There's nothing `try` and `catch` can do about compilation failures.

As I see it, your options are:

- Use Babel or some other transpiler to convert modern JS code to JS code that will run in IE.
- Use a 'plain' `for` loop instead of your `for (xy of x)` loop.  Doing so does not involve a lot of effort, and as I noted in a comment your `for` loop is using the index of the element within the array anyway.

I strongly recommend you give up on your idea of getting IE to ignore a block of code.